# Identify consecutive date periods per group

Tags: python, pandas

Would like to know how I can identify consecutive date periods with the period counter resetting per group.

This is my stab at it which does it across the whole DataFrame but can't workout how to do it per group.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "peoples": ["jimbob","jimbob","jimbob", "jimbob","jimbob","jimbob", "sonnyjim","sonnyjim","sonnyjim","sonnyjim"],
    "dates": ["2020-11-01","2020-11-02","2020-11-03","2020-11-06","2020-11-09","2020-11-10", "2020-11-12","2020-11-13","2020-11-20","2020-11-22"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dates"])

df["period"] = df["dates"].diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()

print(df)
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
    peoples      dates  period
0    jimbob 2020-11-01       1
1    jimbob 2020-11-02       1
2    jimbob 2020-11-03       1
3    jimbob 2020-11-06       2
4    jimbob 2020-11-09       3
5    jimbob 2020-11-10       3
6  sonnyjim 2020-11-12       1
7  sonnyjim 2020-11-13       1
8  sonnyjim 2020-11-20       2
9  sonnyjim 2020-11-22       3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` the dataframe on `peoples` then apply a custom `lambda` function on `dates` to calculate the consecutive date blocks:

```
f = lambda s: s.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()
df['period'] = df.groupby('peoples')['dates'].apply(f)
```

---

```
    peoples      dates  period
0    jimbob 2020-11-01       1
1    jimbob 2020-11-02       1
2    jimbob 2020-11-03       1
3    jimbob 2020-11-06       2
4    jimbob 2020-11-09       3
5    jimbob 2020-11-10       3
6  sonnyjim 2020-11-12       1
7  sonnyjim 2020-11-13       1
8  sonnyjim 2020-11-20       2
9  sonnyjim 2020-11-22       3
```